# Is there a way to specify the icon for a SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider?

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

I'm looking to specify an icon for my application's local search history, but I am not seeing anything in the docs that would allow me to easily add one. To be clear, I am using the built-in Android search API and utilizing a SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider that I have implemented.

Also, I am targeting API level 7.

-Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to accomplish what I had asked, but here's how I did it:

1. Create another ContentProvider and use that in my searchable.xml
2. This new ContentProvider's query method will query my SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider with special parameters and a special URI and return that Cursor.

Source code snippet of my new ContentProvider:

```
...
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        "_id", 
        "display1 AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
        "display2 AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
        "query AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY,
        android.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,
    };
    final Uri URI = 
        Uri.parse("content://" + SearchHistoryProvider.AUTHORITY + "/suggestions");
    return getContext().getContentResolver().query(
        URI, 
        PROJECTION, 
        "display1 LIKE ?", 
        new String[] {selectionArgs[0] + "%"}, 
        "date DESC");
}
...
```

If the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider is not set up to use two lines, 'display2' in the projection above should be changed to 'null' or could probably be omitted altogether.

If the 'suggestions' path is omitted from the URI, it will not work. It must be 'suggestions' otherwise you will see an 'Invalid Uri' Exception.

I dug most of this information up by digging through the source code to SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.

Comment: I used similar solution but I'm getting same icon for all results, but I wanted to make a different icon for all result items. Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding an icon to the provider stanza in the AndroidManifest.xml file? Not sure if it will work, but see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html for the full details about the attributes of the `<provider>` element.